# 1 laptop cannot access Ubuntu file sharing computer

Tags: networking, server, file-sharing

My office has been running 2 Ubuntu Linux boxes for over a year, one of which has a virtual win2K server running.  They have been great; always up.  But one of our 8 PC's is unable to create a Network Place in Windows 10, even though I have confirmed the user names and passwords from existing systems, and validated them on the Linux box.  All other machines connect fine.  The one that can't access the file server, has no trouble connecting to the 2nd Linux box to access the virtual Win2K server running there either.
I tried adding a new user to Linux just for this machine, but it still will not connect.  Suggestions?

**Update**

For clarity; the Network Place is created; it simply will not connect to the destination using the correct user name and password.

Elsewhere I found someone who had a similar issue and the fix he applied did the trick.  here is what worked:

"Run > Secpol.msc
then set Local Policies > Security Options > Network Security: LAN Manager authentication level to 'Send NTLMv2 response only. Refuse LM & NTLM' "   immediately connected!  Thank you for helping!

Comment: For clarity; the Network Place is created; it simply will not connect to the destination using the correct user name and password.

Comment: Don't comment, add infos always to your question. (I just helped out) Use the **edit** link below your question next time

Comment: For clarity, by file server do you mean SAMBA running directly in the Ubuntu or SAMBA running in the virtual Win2k running inside Ubuntu? Also indicate which version of Ubuntu you are running in your next [edit to the question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1401390/edit).

Comment: We are happy that you found the solution to your problem. Please do not put the answer inside the question. Click on the **Answer your own question** button below to write your answer. Then accept your answer as the correct one by clicking on the gray check mark ✓ next to your answer and turn it green  ✅. This will mark the problem as solved and help others.

Comment: Isn't this a Windows problem?

Answer (score 0):

In response to user68186, I hope this is the preferred way to post how the problem was resolved.

Elsewhere I found someone who had a similar issue and the fix he applied did the trick. here is what worked:

"Run > Secpol.msc then set Local Policies > Security Options > Network Security: LAN Manager authentication level to 'Send NTLMv2 response only. Refuse LM & NTLM' " immediately connected!